# Install an old version package with a security related update

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, testing

I am creating some unit tests for my ansible role(OS update) to verify that my os update process has been done successfully. There is a feature to update only security related packages.

To test it, I need to downgrade or install a package (with a security related update) beforehand. And later, after executing the role, I will verify that this update has been installed.

Any recommendation on how to tackle such issue? new ideas are welcomed.

OS: CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

You’re nearly there. “yum downgrade *package name*” will install the previous package available in the yum repo. You can also point it at a package ( or packages) if you have them downloaded already.